# Dark spots on painted wall

Tags: painting, paint

The other day I covered up a mark on a painted wall using the same paint used before with a roller. The paint is Dulux emulsion paint and was stirred before use. It has been almost 24 hours since I applied the paint, but area I have painted over is now darker than the rest of the wall.

What can I do to fix this? What I don't want to do is repaint the entire wall or room.

Comment: How long ago was it originally painted? How old is the paint in the can?  What made the mark that was covered up?

Answer (score 1):

In the original paint job; was the paint thinned before use ?

Did you use a roller or a brush to touch up ?

Sometimes paint settles to the bottom of the can:
How old is the can of the existing paint ?

If the can of paint has been sitting - your paint pigments are stuck and coagulated on the bottom and you will need to mix them in. If you have had it for more than 2 years you are better off doing a paint match.

What you can do is take a piece of paint (a chip) from under an electrical outlet cover to get a match.

Your lid might have a label with the mix parameters printed on it along with a color sample as well. The mix parameters are the best and the match is the next best thing.

You might be able to repaint over the surface depending on how much darker the paint is. Also remember if the room gets plenty of sun light - the paint can fade and that might be what has really occurred.

Comment: The original paint never needed thinning and was stirred before use as I did the second time. Both times a roller was used. There is only about 10 months difference between then and now. The room does get a lot of sun. Should I wait a couple of days?

Comment: If it was me - I would wait a couple days first. Then if it did not clear up try to lighten to touch up one inconspicuous area. if that did not work - (if there is not much to touch up - get a sample of a match - $4 versus $25-$40.

Comment: TBH, a color match from _exposed_ paint (not paint hiding in the dark under an outlet cover) is going to get the best match for _today's_ color as opposed to the paint mix which will get the _original_ color. A lot of sunlight, as noted in the comment, will cause the paint to start fading, even after only 10 months. It'll be slight fading, but it could be noticeable.

Comment: @freeman yes and that's in my answer, but the first point is to verify that the paint in the can hasn't changed, or has been properly mixed for this times use. After that's ruled out fading is last check. Then match the faded paint via samples because surface might not be smooth and also factors with mixing different brands lots etc..